# Return value based on contents of array

Tags: c#, arrays

Whats the best way to return the ID's from this array that have started and but not ended. I've been trying to loop though for matching ID's, and then check for the status being "started" or "ended", but I keep matching with the ID and Status that I picked for sorting. (I.e I pick array[0,0] and look for ID 5847 it will get a match on itself).

```
array[0,0] = "5847"
array[0,1] = "started"
array[1,0] = "5846"
array[1,1] = "ended"
array[2,0] = "5846"
array[2,1] = "started"
array[3,0] = "5845"
array[3,1] = "ended"
array[4,0] = "5845"
array[4,1] = "started"
array[5,0] = "5844"
array[5,1] = "ended"
```

Comment: can you confirm that you have object defined in row in this object. that [X,1] is the state for the [x,0] id?

Comment: Thats exactly how it works. [x,0] is the ID, and [x,1] is the state of that ID.

Comment: I added an answer assuming this. with an exemple. It should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project your 2D into an object as you seems to have row based object.
Then group on the ID, and take the max of the Ended=1/Started=0

```
var result =
   Enumerable
    .Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
    .Select(row => new Foo { id = int.Parse(array[row, 0]), ended = (array[row, 1] == "ended") })
    .GroupBy(g=> g.id)
    .Select( g=> new { Id=g.Key, MaxEnded= g.Max(r=> r.ended)})
    .Where(x=> !x.MaxEnded);
```

[C# Exemple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gehXQS)

Comment: This looks good but I'm getting an error on result.Dump(). Being it has no refrence to dump inside IEnumerable<foo>.

Comment: Yes because Dump is a function use on DotFiddle to Dump a variable to show its content.

Comment: If you want to display content use the good old `foreach(var item in foos){Console.WriteLine(Item.property);}`

Comment: Ohh I see. I don't use DotFiddle and I thought I had missed something. Thanks.

Comment: Final Question, should I just check if result returns null if none of them apply?

Comment: For a foreach you don't have to check I guess it depends on what you will do with the thing. so with little information like I will say. the better you guard yourself from error the better you are.